# Scraping captcha with python

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, captcha

I'm a newbie in web-scryping and trying to scrape the website [www.mediamarkt.de](http://www.mediamarkt.de) with python and beautifulsoup. But if I request the website with the following commands

```
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")
```

I always get a response with a captcha and the following html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
 <head>
  <title>
   MediaMarkt
  </title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
  <link href="favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
  <style>
   html{background:#f2f2f2}body{background:#fff;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;line-height:1.5;margin:0 auto;max-width:775px;padding:3% 5%}h1{font-size:40px;font-weight:300;margin:0;padding:0}img{height:auto;max-width:100%}a{color:#000;text-decoration:underline}.cf:after{clear:both;content:".";display:block;height:0;visibility:hidden}.cf{margin-bottom:40px}.cf a{float:right}p{margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:0}span{font-weight:700}@media only screen and (max-width:768px){body{margin:0 auto;padding:3%;width:94%}.cf a{display:block;float:none}.cf a,h1{text-align:center}}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
    (function(){
      window._cf_chl_opt={
        cvId: "2",
        cType: "interactive",
        cNounce: "72954",
        cRay: "64146bb44c96874d",
        cHash: "180a9c834f793db",
        cFPWv: "b",
        cTTimeMs: "4000",
        cLt: "n",
        cRq: {
          ru: "aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubWVkaWFtYXJrdC5kZS9kZS9wcm9kdWN0L19wbGF5c3RhdGlvbi00JUUyJTg0JUEyLTUwMGdiLWJsYWNrLXBsYXlzdGF0aW9uLTQta29uc29sZW4tMjQ5MDMxNC5odG1s",
          ra: "TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKFgxMTsgTGludXggeDg2XzY0KSBBcHBsZVdlYktpdC81MzcuMzYgKEtIVE1MLCBsaWtlIEdlY2tvKSBDaHJvbWUvODkuMC40Mzg5LjExNCBTYWZhcmkvNTM3LjM2IE9QUi83NS4wLjM5NjkuMTcx",
          rm: "R0VU",
          d: "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",
          t: "MTYxODY0OTU4Mi43OTQwMDA=",
          m: "d/ZnRg0EL9z2kNXGa+OTY1aNzDccyF9LkSDFY3REpvQ=",
          i1: "AqlZZg1sW7V1MVxeolQRPQ==",
          i2: "DKd2Vlnqw4vEdVWAEGLh5Q==",
          zh: "q1ZR4e29hYz+cTx2o5UYJG1hFifFh0loDJNTfBOG7gU=",
          uh: "llvEwksvBQLa3qw+2GF57m2hqVmANZAE8hpLp0VjYgw=",
          hh: "+dgxVyY+fQBum8yrY3Q9pqqEvjydD2WPU3jRaUrPF1o=",
        }
      };
    }());
    //]]>
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="cf">
   <a href="index.html">
    <img alt="logo" class="logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" width="200"/>
   </a>
  </div>
  <p>
   Lieber Besucher,
  </p>
  <p>
   Das ging uns leider zu schnell. Um fortzufahren und alle Angebote von Mediamarkt zu sehen, vervollständigen Sie bitte nachfolgendes Captcha.
  </p>
  <form action="/de/product/_playstation-4%E2%84%A2-500gb-black-playstation-4-konsolen-2490314.html?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=674429051038517c70900376fe1726911a6a4760-1618649582-0-AZ7lglgU5r8RhHYydYvhTplT7dt9gFvh-obcy0PdqcXFGVq6GCq8bTeiqjg6vpfJrnuOseXVaEoQUVDHeHiBOYzLiCym93witbCjGuIIjapdnmTgWvRy9euNozX2O-oDrEUy80eR_ltdSbgZV-6nbslELrIWq1U5b2R8ZyaQp_xmkeeH4WAYTgx5RK9C6oop8GychujPrb0Y_TbQCI-WLjVTdRnVU_amQJevetRBhxkDb0iHlM3q-RrSD2LWYD7eJpfGNE1P11xgzfmfMThF6VUTyiXo8pr7SXpJOgNNglNZge-PEyrr13lCkSoraWrwQfiZP4lv0qjJz-fnLsreRGg3d8MyPmDDUEHVYawGIyVZ5iKS4LGNtCjkzDIZgu7GAuPam6Y8QvAOqZE1Y-xCue1ChoVUfA_6dICcUZfcn1WIkpMs8GmkdsCNztN1Z6RlKf1qzSDEkbtmZOvrtXIshjyphxcDt64GSBxHPnYUYVB5VQ4rcgKJlPOiya_t7zbSQurlfH3dNzESvsV-gbbAuWhhinwJgavPXc5UTU-FGvWwU3FahBihl4CXAgEq9_kKoH7frNRVg0farz5_X9JFHG5mCMNLWPMvkZLWug9Gyst379JhADxFxods2K8CCARCWBTxRkKRBHs7usJze7zpjGMJl9jms1BCTRMqKhXbSUDJct1Fw1UW4IwNNAqrhRXBcgO76sOvlkY1SsA0n_uHbrw" class="challenge-form interactive-form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="challenge-form" method="POST">
   <div id="cf-please-wait">
    <div id="spinner">
     <div id="cf-bubbles">
      <div class="bubbles">
      </div>
      <div class="bubbles">
      </div>
      <div class="bubbles">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <p data-translate="please_wait" id="cf-spinner-please-wait">
     Please stand by, while we are checking your browser...
    </p>
    <p data-translate="redirecting" id="cf-spinner-redirecting" style="display:none">
     Redirecting...
    </p>
   </div>
   <input name="r" type="hidden" value="afa37c5b28edb0710a4e24c5ef026cf8c401b420-1618649582-0-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"/>
   <input name="cf_captcha_kind" type="hidden" value="h"/>
   <input name="vc" type="hidden" value="f82577da64d463ea2c27e47342148825"/>
   <noscript class="cf-captcha-info" id="cf-captcha-bookmark">
    <h1 data-translate="turn_on_js" style="color:#bd2426;">
     Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.
    </h1>
   </noscript>
   <div class="cookie-warning" data-translate="turn_on_cookies" id="no-cookie-warning" style="display:none">
    <p data-translate="turn_on_cookies" style="color:#bd2426;">
     Please enable Cookies and reload the page.
    </p>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var a = function() {try{return !!window.addEventListener} catch(e) {return !1} },
      b = function(b, c) {a() ? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", b, c) : document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", b)};
      b(function(){
        var cookiesEnabled=(navigator.cookieEnabled)? true : false;
        if(!cookiesEnabled){
          var q = document.getElementById('no-cookie-warning');q.style.display = 'block';
        }
      });
  //]]>
   </script>
   <div id="trk_captcha_js" style="background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/captcha/nojs/h/transparent.gif?ray=64146bb44c96874d')">
   </div>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
    (function(){
        var isIE = /(MSIE|Trident\/|Edge\/)/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
        var trkjs = isIE ? new Image() : document.createElement('img');
        trkjs.setAttribute("src", "/cdn-cgi/images/trace/captcha/js/transparent.gif?ray=64146bb44c96874d");
        trkjs.id = "trk_captcha_js";
        trkjs.setAttribute("alt", "");
        document.body.appendChild(trkjs);
        var cpo=document.createElement('script');
        cpo.type='text/javascript';
        cpo.src="/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/orchestrate/captcha/v1?ray=64146bb44c96874d";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
    }());
    //]]>
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

My idea was to download the picture behind "/cdn-cgi/images/trace/captcha/js/transparent.gif?ray=64146bb44c96874d" but this wasn't a captcha.

So my question is: Can someone tell me what type of captcha this is and whether it is possible to solve it with python?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is Cloudfare. It's used to protect websites against DDoS attacks. I'd recommend you find another site to scrape from, since it'll be a mess to compete with. However, if you really want to scrape from this site, I recommend you use the [cloudscraper](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/) module to bypass it.